# svg.js position text in middle of path

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I am trying to use svg.js to achieve positioning text on the middle of a path.
Below I can achieve it via svg ...

```html
<svg width="140" height="140">
<defs>
    <path id="textPlot" d="M68,27 L 51 31 39 39 29 52 26 69 31 86 41 99 55 108 70 111 86 108 99 98 107 85 111 68 106 49 99 39 87 30" fill="#ddd" stroke="#ddd"></path>
</defs>
<text style="font-size: 20px;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textPlot" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">text align in middle</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

[image of text on path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usNVb.png)

Here is the current javascript code Im using to try and achieve the above. But Im not aware of any other attribute on the svg.js API to specify that the text should be positioned on the middle baseline of the path.

```
SVG('svgNodeId').text('center my text in path')
.attr({id:'myText'})
.font({size:15})
.path('M65,25 L 42 35 28 53 27 77 37 93 52 103 69 108 90 100 104 84z');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `<textPath>` child by calling `text.textPath()`. When you have that element you can set all attributes you want.

```
SVG('svgNodeId').text('center my text in path')
  .attr({id:'myText'})
  .font({size:15})
  .path('M65,25 L 42 35 28 53 27 77 37 93 52 103 69 108 90 100 104 84z')
  .textPath()
  .attr({startOffset: '50%', 'text-anchor': 'middle'})
```